# How do I get an XNA 4.0 game to run on other machines?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

Whenever I try and run a game made in XNA 4.0 on a machine other than one used for development, it just won't run. I've followed the instructions [here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/1988.aspx) to ensure that all the dependencies are present.

To be clear I've done the following:

1. Downloaded and installed the [Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=E5AD0459-CBCC-4B4F-97B6-FB17111CF544&displaylang=en).
2. Downloaded and installed the [Microsoft XNA Framework Redistributable 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a88c6dec-aeae-42cd-a108-d35c013c3b97&displaylang=en).
3. Made sure I am not using anything contained within `GamerServices` and `XNA.Net.*`, my references are as follows:

> Microsoft.Xna.Framework
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Avatar
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Video
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Xact
>   mscorlib
>   System System.Core
>   System.Windows.Forms
>   System.Xml
>   System.Xml.Linq

I also followed the advice [here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/10676.aspx) to ensure the problem was not within the code itself.

---

I've tried the follow methods to get it to run (on both Vista and 7):

- Use the built in publishing functionality. This results in an error saying that `Microsoft.Xna.Input.Touch` needs to be present in the GAC. I've tried adding `Microsoft.Xna.Input.Touch` to the references, and this does not fix the issue.
- Copy the XNA dll files locally. This results in an error message stating that `Microsoft.Xna.Game.dll or one of its dependencies could not be located`.
- Copy over everything contained in `Release`. This results in an `Application X stopped working...` or `APPCRASH` error message the second it starts. My code is never reached.

Is there any way to get this to work? I've been trying to get this to work with the deadline looming, and it's been a source of unneeded stress.

Comment: Make sure your XNA project actually targets the .NET Client 4.0 profile. I've seen people make that mistake. Could you say what happens when you run it. Does something come up?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I forgot to mention that. It does target the .NET Client 4.0 profile. All the output that ever happens it in the question (nothing ever shows but the error).

Comment: Make sure the appropriate version of DirectX is installed on that machine?

Comment: @Omnion I'm reasonably sure that the XNA redistributable bundles the appropriate version of DirectX.

Comment: There were issues of this in the earlier versions. I simply forgot :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A clue may lie in the fact that there shouldn't be any Xna.Input.Touch reference in a windows project - XNA 4.0 only supports touch on WP7. Are you sure you have XNA 4.0 installed and not the *beta*, which did support Xna.Input.Touch on windows?

Comment: This is the first thing I thought of when I saw Microsoft.Xna.Input.Touch. If OP is developing with XNA 4.0 rtw but started the project with the beta, he's got some munging to do to update references.

Comment: Yes, this was it. Even though I had the correct version of XNA, VS insisted on using the old assemblies (which were somehow still kicking around). Thanks for the answer.